# Xamarin OneSignal : An error occurred trying to install required android components on Project 'PushNotificationEx.Android'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, onesignal

> An error occurred trying to install required android components on
>   Project 'PushNotificationEx.Android'. Project
>   'PushNotificationEx.Android' requires the following components
>   installed on your machine:  Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base
>   JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r22.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.1.0/play-services-base-8.1.0.aar-8.1.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r22.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.1.0/play-services-base-8.1.0.aar-8.1.0
>   Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r22.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/8.1.0/play-services-basement-8.1.0.aar-8.1.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r22.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/8.1.0/play-services-basement-8.1.0.aar-8.1.0
>   Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r22.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/8.1.0/play-services-gcm-8.1.0.aar-8.1.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r22.zip-m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/8.1.0/play-services-gcm-8.1.0.aar-8.1.0
>
> Please double-click here to install it.
>
> Intallation Errors: XA5207 Please install package: 'GPS Base'
>   available in SDK installer. Java library file
>   'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base\8.1.0\embedded\classes.jar'
>   doesn't exist. XA5207 Please install package: 'GPS Basement' available
>   in SDK installer. Java library file 'C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\classes.jar' doesn't exist.
>   XA5207 Please install package: 'GPS GCM' available in SDK installer.
>   Java library file 'C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\classes.jar' doesn't exist.

I want to do push notification through onesignal . I'm getting this error after installing 'Com.OneSignal' package  in my project. double clicking also not working..Please help..

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Components are no longer supported in VS 2017 and on.

Comment: VisualStudio Community 2017. Version 15.6.2

Comment: Okay, have you looked at my answer? It should solve your issue.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If so, please mark it as the answer so that others can benefit from it. Thanks!

Comment: Okay but your original problem has been solved, correct? If you have another question, post it a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with OneSignal. You are most likely using an outdated Xamarin Forms project with a new version of Visual Studio 2017. Just to test this, I created a brand new Xamarin Forms project in VS 2017 and added OneSignal and it built just fine.

This problem stems from the lack of support for Xamarin Components in the most recent versions of VS 2017. To fix this problem, either follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/component-nuget) on Microsoft's website or start over with new Xamarin Forms project.